# Don’t know how to solve the error “times is not defined”

Tags: discord.js

I keep getting the error:

```
for(i=0; i<num; i++){
     ^
ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Ploatjs/dist/index.js:52:18)
    at Client.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at Client.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/Ploatjs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:26:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/Ploatjs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/Ploatjs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/Ploatjs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/Ploatjs/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/Ploatjs/node_modules/ws/lib/even-target.js:199:18)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

With this code:

```js
if(message.content.startsWith("p!generate")){
    let args = message.content.split(" ");
    let num = args[1]
    if(isNaN(num)) return message.reply("Number of generate must be numeric.")
    let array = ["Common", "Uncommon", "Rare", "Epic", "Legendary", "Exotic", "Mythic"]
    let items = []
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
        let item = array[rand]
        items.push(item)
    }
    message.channel.send(items.join(", "))
  }
})
```

My code is designed to generate a chosen number of rarities and send it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your list an array.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
if(message.content.startsWith("p!generate")){

let args = message.content.split(" ");
let num = args[1]
if(isNaN(num)) return message.reply("Number of generate must be numeric.")

let array = ["Common", "Uncommon", "Rare", "Epic", "Legendary", "Exotic", "Mythic"]
let items = []
let i = 0;
while (i<num){
let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
let item = array[rand]
items.push(item)
i++
}

message.channel.send(items.join(", "))
}
})
```

Comment: Edited the question because I found errors with this code.

Comment: Not i < times; i<num... Use exact this code.. Also you broke for loop please just copy this code and use it. Don't  forget brackets.

Comment: With this code the error:

i is not defined pops up

Comment: Can you share error with this code? Because I don't see any errors on here.

Comment: The error shows up only when you type p!generate (number)

Comment: edited question to add more in depth error code

Comment: I edited that line of code look at.

Answer (score 0):

As per your current question, you are getting the error `i is not defined` because you have not defined `i` as a variable yet you are using it in the for loop. All you have to do is change the first line of the for loop to:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    //...
}
```